# Why does Maven waste over 12 seconds?

Tags: maven

Simply put, I get this result

```
$ time mvn generate-sources ; date
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building connect-ui 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ connect-ui ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

<Ant task that does a copy followed by a search and replace.>

[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-19T18:14:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/311M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

real    0m13.057s
user    0m15.760s
sys 0m0.246s
Tue May 19 18:14:26 CEST 2015

    real    0m13.036s
    user    0m15.807s
    sys 0m0.292s
```

By Maven's output, it would seem that the task is complete. And indeed, the source it generated is available right after the BUILD SUCCESS has been printed.

But clearly it is wasting some more time. What can it be, and how do I make Maven stop wasting those 12 seconds?

FWIW,

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

Running with -X (or --debug) makes no difference - Maven still says `BUILD SUCCESS` and then there is a waiting period (with no further output).

For fun I also tried mvn clean test:

```
time mvn -X clean ; date
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T22:58:10+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.299 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-19T18:22:44+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/291M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

real    0m12.805s
user    0m14.739s
sys 0m0.196s
Tue May 19 18:22:56 CEST 2015
```

Comment: Have you tried running in debug mode to get more information regarding what it's doing?

Comment: I tried that now. No difference. Question updated.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen Does the extra 12 seconds happen before or after Maven prints "BUILD SUCCESS"?

Comment: @matts it happens after.

Comment: Can you use 'strace' to see what exactly is happening when the process executes?

Comment: Not too familiar with that. $ time sudo dtruss mvn generate-sources gives me real 0m3.847s
user 0m0.182s
sys 0m3.647s

Comment: Perhaps one of your plugins is spawning a child process or something like that.  Is the ant plugin the only one executing?

Comment: Tried mvn clean also, similar results time-wise.

Comment: Not to go on a tangent, but I had similar issue. In my case, the problem was I was using git bash to also issue mvn commands... and my git user directory was also a network mapped drive. So it was git bash that was slow in my case.

Comment: What looks a little bit strange to me is the line `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec` How did you install Maven (Downloaded from page via .tar.gz )? Furthermore is JAVA_HOME explicitly set or will be evaluated in some kind? How have you configured memory for Maven JVM ?

Comment: Have you tried to do `time mvn --version`? Furthermore make a separate empty maven pom.xml and try the same `time mvn clean` on it...If `mvn clean` takes the same time someone could bound some plugins to the clean life cycle...

Comment: @khmarbaise `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec` is the path, when Maven is installed using Homebrew on Mac OS (but in this case, Homebrew just downloads the tar and unpacks it in that location plus adding a symlink to PATH).

Comment: time mvn version: 0.454s